# How to scale based on DPI while preserving font's AutoScaleMode

Tags: c#, winforms

[image: Screenshot]

The above is a screenshot of the issue I will try to describe.

We have a form that's called from outlook integration, which in turn calls a control and places it on a tab. When the user changes their DPI settings, the control no longer will fill the tab, and some of the text is truncated.

I was able to change the form settings to DPI and then detect the size of the control area, and re-size the control based on the values I'd found. This unfortunately is not an acceptable fix. We have a public facing interface that uses the font AutoScaleMode, so I'm stuck trying to find a workaround.

I had decided to detect whether the DPI had changed from the initial 96dpi settings, and if so, call a form that does have the AutoScaleMode set to DPI, leaving the other form intact and the default. While this works, it doesn't really help with the customer Api.

Is there any other way to repair this issue without having multiple forms for base DPI settings, and then calling the form that fits?

Comment: Am little unclear, Why can't you change `AutoScaleMode` ? You've exposed public `API` with it?

Comment: According to the guy that does the code review, changing the AutoScaleMode to DPI will cause issues with users who are using this form with their own fonts.